# Is the theorem 5.7 given in Apostol's Mathematical Analysis correct?

Tags: real-analysis, differential

I came across this theorem in Apostol's Mathematical Analysis and the proof makes sense and seems to be correct.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-sRgtgGlQ5N8h9Vq5eosftjcEbOavOv0/view?usp=drivesdk

However, I also encountered this counterexample in the book 'Counterexamples in Analysis' by Gelbaum and Olmstead. I think I am missing something here and these two might be different, but I am not able to say how.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-sNtOdB06WBH5_unbgdJSdpUEugK2IeS/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: This is a very obvious result (immediate consequenceoof definition of derivative) but unfortunately students don't realize it. The conclusion of the theorem can be restated as $f$ is *strictly increasing at point $c$*. It is different from saying that $f$ is strictly increasing in some neighborhood of $c$.

Comment: Real analysis is the evil twin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a somewhat subtle point.

The theorem in the first link is saying that there is a neighborhood of $c$ such that if $x$ is in that neighborhood then $f(x)-f(c)$ has the same sign as $x-c$. This does not mean that $f$ is increasing on a neighborhood of $c$, which would amount to saying that there exists a neighborhood of $c$ such that if $x,y$ are both in that neighborhood then $f(x)-f(y)$ has the same sign as $x-y$.

The counterexample given in the second link shows that in general being differentiable on $(a,b)$ with $f'(c)> 0$ doesn't imply that $f$ is increasing on a neighborhood of $c$.

Note that being *continuously* differentiable with $f'(c)>0$ does imply that $f$ is increasing on a neighborhood of $c$, but the counterexample in the second link is not continuously differentiable.

To visualize this, it can help to graph $g(x)=x+2x^2$ and $h(x)=x-2x^2$; the graph of $f$ bounces back and forth between the graph of $g$ and the graph of $h$ faster and faster as you approach $x=0$. But now think about the graphs of $g$ and $h$ themselves: both $g$ and $h$ have the same sign as $x$ as long as $|x|<1/2$. Therefore the same is true of $f$.

Comment: Ohh.. I see. Thankyou so much. It makes sense now.